# List of radio inputs with RactiveJS

Tags: radio-button, ractivejs

I have a very funny problem with `RactiveJS`. I know this is the expected behavior, but I cannot see any solution/workaround.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/qsgatse1/2/

The problem comes from this line:

```
<input type='radio' name="{{a}}" value="{{false}}">false
```

In a few words, I have a **Ractive** object, referencing an array of "**sub-ractive**" objects. The **Ractive** and each **SubRactive** have its own template. The value contained in each **SubRactive** is represented in the `DOM` by a radio input.

The fun comes from the fact that each radio input of the subractive have the same "name" attribute if we consider the `DOM` point of view (so they belongs to the same "radio group"), because they have the same keypath. From the point of view of a **SubRactive**, the radio inputs are independent from the ones of the others **SubRactives**.

Is there a way to disambiguate this use case? I cannot merge the **Ractive** and the **SubRactives** into a single **Ractive** object, because each **SubRactive** has also other "**SubSubRactives**" (and so on) and some behaviour/observers that cannot be moved easily.

Comment: I think this is same issue: https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1937

Comment: Apologies, I somehow accidently clicked on the down-vote for your question! Was not intentional and apparently I cannot remove it. Apparently if you edit it I can revote, so if it matters, please make a trivial edit and I will change.

Comment: I have just edited, so that you can revert your downvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your overall design supports it, you can wrap each set of `input`s in a `form` tag. (see http://jsfiddle.net/mqf60w8v/)

```
<form>
<input type='radio' name="{{a}}" value="{{false}}">false
<input type='radio' name="{{a}}" value="{{true}}">true
</form>
```